# Handle Soap Fault Using JaxBElement

Tags: web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, jaxb2

Problem is 
WSDL we have used for generating JAXBElement does not contain SOAP Faults where as the service can return Soap Faults in response.

Now when the service is returning faults and I use my JaxBElement, it throws an exception.
Is there a way I can handle (parse) these Soap Faults and get the error message or description from it.